# How to force Xamarin Forms TabbedPage to scroll to selected tab programmatically on Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

If I have more tabs than fit the screen, on Android I can set the tabmode to scrollable. But if I programmatically set the selected item (either with SelectedItem or CurrentPage) to a tab out of the screen, on Android, the tabs doesn't scroll.

On UWP it's working fine, on iOS it doesn't work because it uses the "more" button. But on Android, it is selecting the right Child, displaying its content, but not scrolling the tabs to the right tab (if it's out of the screen).

If I scroll the tabs manually, the right tab is selected, but this user experience is really bad.

Clearly a bug with Xamarin Forms, but I'm not expecting any change on that soon, so any ideas on how to scroll the tabs programmatically?

Here's the bug report with a sample app to see the problem.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58441

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I programmatically set the selected item (either with SelectedItem or CurrentPage) to a tab out of the screen, on Android, the tabs doesn't scroll. Code like this :

You could write a [TabbedPageRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/) in Xamarin.Android, scrolling the tabs to the right tab.

```
 public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
 {
     private TabLayout tabLayout = null;

     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
     {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);

         this.tabLayout = (TabLayout)this.GetChildAt(1);

         var selectPosition = this.tabLayout.SelectedTabPosition;

         tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
         tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;

         Handler h = new Handler();
         Action myAction = () =>
         {
             tabLayout.GetTabAt(selectPosition).Select();
         };

         h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1);
     }
 }
```

**Effect :**

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks! I miss native skills. I hope you don't mind asking you if it would be possible to use the same scrollable tabs system in iOS, without the "more" button. I can ask a new question if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Source code

```
    <local:Notify Title="Notify" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Notify.ico}"/>
<local:Note Title="Note" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Note.ico}"/>
<local:Weather Title="Weather" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Weather.ico}"/>
<local:Calender Title="Calendar" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Calendar.ico}"/>
```

Change Index

```
    <local:Note Title="Note" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Note.ico}"/>
<local:Notify Title="Notify" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Notify.ico}"/>
<local:Weather Title="Weather" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Weather.ico}"/>
<local:Calender Title="Calendar" IconImageSource="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.Calendar.ico}"/>
```

More Easy...^_^